# App crashes on ZKFileArchive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, zip

I've build my app to download a few zip-files with sizes from 10 up to 25 MB.
After download to the local documents folder I fire the ZKFileArchive method to unzip to that same folder.

In debug modus (device/simulator) all works fine. When I create a release which I install, the app crashes when it reaches

```
ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:filePath];
```

With NSZombie enabled it throws me this:

```
  Thread 10 Crashed:
  0   Hoppr iOS                         0x0003318c +[ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:] (ZKFileArchive.m:185)
  1   Hoppr iOS                         0x00004092 -[LaunchDownload inflateFile:withDict:] (LaunchDownload.m:348)
  2   Foundation                        0x33fbeb8a 0x33fb3000 + 48010
  3   Foundation                        0x33fb7b90 0x33fb3000 + 19344
  4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x32d27b44 0x32c9c000 + 572228
  5   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x32d197a4 0x32c9c000 + 513956
```

Could this be a memory issue? From times to times it throws me a level 1 memory warning, but as I've been reading this should not cause too much problems.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

The top of this logfile:

```
  Incident Identifier: 1BEC1CCB-AD95-4A06-8F4F-3DA1A2A4F18D
  CrashReporter Key:   36fcd8536ee68a7e6b261ba23f2ec090b98d388e
  Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
  Process:         Hoppr iOS [1340]
  Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/47587D8A-AE7E-4C26-9C23-9394DE268E69/Hoppr iOS.app/Hoppr iOS
  Identifier:      Hoppr iOS
  Version:         ??? (???)
  Code Type:       ARM (Native)
  Parent Process:  launchd [1]

  Date/Time:       2011-03-16 15:49:22.041 +0100
  OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
  Report Version:  104

  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
  Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe92d0d00
  Crashed Thread:  10
```

Comment: We need to see more code and we need to know what the cause of the crash was (should be at the top of that log) e.g. EXC_BAD_ACCESS etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework you are linking looks like it was not built for the target platform.  `Illegal instruction` means there is something very wrong with the binary.